# How to use/display rundeck's webhook payload?

Tags: webhooks, rundeck

I'm triggering a rundeck job with webhook received from gitlab.
I want to be able to use some of the parameters received in the payload, f.e, printing the user triggering the job.
Tried to use it like they suggest here https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/webhooks/run-job.html#configuration but without success...

Can anyone here show me a simple example of how to use it?

Much appreciated :)

---

Update:

Managed to pass the payload as an option and use it later in a script block

```
-whkpayload ${raw}
```

and the script

```
echo message=@option.whkpayload@
```

you can resolve this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

how did you get your eventual solution to work?  I've only been able to suss out that one needs to write an intermediary to receive the hook from GitLab then issue a new hook to Rundeck with the payload and headers tweaked appropriately.